# Force editText to go back to main layout on "Enter"

Tags: android-widget

I have a series of EditTexts for numeric input.
Right now when the user inputs a number in the first field and presses "Enter", focus goes to the next field.
I'd like for the screen input to go away and get back to the main screen layout instead.
How do you achieve this?
Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Register the [key listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) on your edit text and handle the enter key event and use the following code to close the soft keyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I can't make it work, at least as far as I know to try (I'm a novice)   I replaced the "myEditText" with my EditText id and inserted the code snippet directly after setting the text for the EditText.  Maybe I need to read up on key listeners...